# Go ZeroMQ: Linker problem when trying to build in VS Code on Windows

Tags: windows, go, zeromq

In short, I want to do the following thing:
Use https://github.com/pebbe/zmq4 and run a simple example, like [hello world](https://github.com/pebbe/zmq4/blob/master/examples/hwclient.go) in VS Code on Windows.
When building, I get these kinds of errors

```
<Windows Homedir>/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b299\_x008.o: in function `zmq4_bind':
<GOPATH>/pkg/mod/github.com/pebbe/zmq4@v1.2.9/wrappers_windows.go:27: undefined reference to `__imp_zmq_bind'
```

What I did so far:

- Install Visual Studio, since it was required by vcpkg install
- Install [libzmq](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq) using `vcpkg.exe install libzmq:x64-windows` (default is 32 bit installation, which I did first by mistake. I hope there is no leftover from this somewhere that's causing problems.)
- Set the required Go environment variables in VS Code Terminal (PowerShell). After some trying, it seemed to me that this has to be done like this:

```
go env -w CGO_CFLAGS='-I <Windows Homedir>\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include'
go env -w CGO_LDFLAGS='-LD:<Windows Homedir>\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib -L:libzmq-mt-4_3_4.lib'
```

- Install TDM-GCC
- Add `<Windows Homedir>\TDM-GCC-64\bin`, `<Windows Homedir>\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib` and `<Windows Homedir>\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include` to %Path% environment variable

I'm using Go version go1.18.4 windows/amd64 and VS Code 1.74.1 on Windows 10 Enterprise.

I have no clue what to try next, so any hints are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using a wrong a wrong syntax for the linker flags. [https://github.com/pebbe/zmq4](https://github.com/pebbe/zmq4#windows) has lead me on a wrong track. It should be `CGO_LDFLAGS='-L <Windows Homedir>/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib -l libzmq-mt-4_3_4'`